# calculate the execution time in 2 different devices

Tags: python, time, virtual-machine, delay

I want to measure the delay of a system which works in 2 different python scripts in different devices ie one in the local pc and other in the virtual machine.

In simple words, i need to measure the delay when the script in virtual machine start and when its gets the feedback from the local pc .

I tried with the time module where i can find the start and end time and subtracting them gives the duration of the process.
Since different devices have different time references. It would not give an accurate answer.
I want to know if there is any way to find the delay in 2 different devices.

Hoping to get some ideas on how to do it.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be accurate? The relative time of each device eg. 3 seconds passing, would still be 3 seconds passing even if they're not calibrated to the same date and time.

Comment: Ok but is there any other way to do it

Comment: Use a third device (or process) which you can message to keep time. A tells C when it "starts", and B tells C when it starts. They can tell tell C when they finish. So for instance, before your virtual machine asks your pc to do some work, it tells timing process it's going to ask your pc. Then when your pc responds, it can tell timing process - giving you the time it took.